# Core Data - Create Initial Data on First Open, Then Load it into NSTableView - OSX

Tags: swift, macos, core-data, nstableview, nsmanagedobject

i need to insert the days of the week Mon -> Sunday into core data, because you cant set data into core data from interface builder im doing this when the app first opens like this...

```
let firstLaunchCheck = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "nonya-buisness ;)")

    if firstLaunchCheck?.boolForKey("firstLaunch") == false {
        print("First Launch")


        let appDel = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDel.managedObjectContext

        let addDay =  NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Weekdays", inManagedObjectContext: context)

        let dayIndex = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

        var dayNumber = 0

        for day in dayIndex {

            print(day)

            addDay.setValue(day, forKey: "dayName")
            addDay.setValue(dayNumber, forKey: "dayNumber")

            if dayNumber >= 5 {
                addDay.setValue(true, forKey: "dayHoliday")
            } else {
                addDay.setValue(false, forKey: "dayHoliday")
            }

            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch let error as NSError  {
                print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }

            dayNumber++
        }

        firstLaunchCheck?.setBool(true, forKey: "firstLaunch")
        firstLaunchCheck?.synchronize()
    } else {
        print("App has already been opened")
    }
```

Im storing the dayName and the dayNumber (eg, Wednesday is 2) and also adding wheather or not the day is a holiday or not. By default its set to Saturday and sunday (This can be changed by the user later)

Next in my view did load method im trying to load my data, this is where im getting stuck i think...

```
var TimetableData = [NSManagedObject]()

super.viewDidLoad() {
let appDel = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDel.managedObjectContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Weekdays")
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "dayNumber", ascending: false)]

    do {
        let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
        TimetableData = results as! [NSManagedObject]
        print(TimetableData.count)
        DayTableView.reloadData()

    } catch {
        print("There was a problem retrieving saved data")
}
}
```

The actually representing the data in a table view i dont think is the problem, but heres the code anyway.

```
if tableView == DayTableView {

        let savedData = TimetableData[row]

            let cell : NextDayCell = DayTableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("nextDayCell", owner: self) as! NextDayCell





            if savedData.valueForKey("dayHoliday") as? Bool == true {
                cell.cellDayString.stringValue = savedData.valueForKey("dayName") as! String + " Weekday"
            } else {
                cell.cellDayString.stringValue = savedData.valueForKey("dayName") as! String
            }
            cell.dayNumberS.stringValue = "\(day)"

            day++

            return cell

}
```

For some reason all this code is only loading 1 thing from core data, and that is Sunday. Help me ;P thanks people in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do one `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` and change the properties of this object for each day. The solution is to do `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` for each day.

Comment: perfect, just had to move my addDay variable to inside the for loop and it worked, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If the question here is really about CoreData, then I'm sure there will be another answer very soon.

If the real requirement is about accessing the days of the week, there is a simpler approach

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter() 
// dateFormatter.weekdaySymbols = "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

for dayIndex in days
{    
    print(dateFormatter.weekdaySymbols[dayIndex])
}
```

Comment: Im using this approach because my app revolves around what day of the week it is, and it needs lots of other information than just the day name. For example the tableview this is being added to is the nvaigation of all the days and depending on the data it changes what the view will display. But thanks for the new way to get day names